# How to detect empty spaces in a string?

Tags: java, string

```
               String  test="This is a simple text"
```

Is it possible to detect spaces and write next line by looking this spaces? I mean to have a console output like this:

```
                      This is a simple text
                      ++++ ++ + ++++++ ++++
```

Comment: For each character, if it's not a space, write a `+`, otherwise write a space.

Comment: Have a look at [`Character.isWhitespace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isWhitespace(char)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class StringPlus {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String  test="This is a simple text";
        for(char c: test.toCharArray()){
            System.out.print((c == ' ') ? " ":"+");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
String orig = "This is a simple text";
String newString = orig.replaceAll("[^\\s]", "+");
```

It uses regular expression to replace all character which are not white-space with plus sign.

Comment: Actually, all characters that are not whitespace (tabs, spaces, newlines). In this case it may work, although you could just use a negated space.

Answer (score 1):

Iterate through the `String`, while concatenating to a new `String` with each iteration.  If a character in the original `String` is not equal to a space, concatenate a `+` to the new string, otherwise concatenate a space to the new `String`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest approach is to loop through and build it up manually. Other approaches could involve using a regex (for example, if you know the set of input characters) in conjunction with `string.replace`.

Here's what a loop could look like:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(inputString.length);
for (char c : inputString) {
  if (Character.isWhiteSpace(c)) {
    sb.append("*");
  } else {
    sb.append(" ");
}
return sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Character.isWhitespace(ch)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isWhitespace%28char%29), e.g.

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    String test = "This is a simple text";
    System.out.println(test);
    for (char ch : test.toCharArray()) {
        System.out.print(Character.isWhitespace(ch) ? " " : "+");
    }
}
```